# Similarity between Min-Conflicts and Coordinate Descent in CSPs?

Tags: optimization, constraint-satisfaction

I'm currently writing a library that solves a specific type of problem that involves mainly constraint satisfaction.

I have came across the [Min-Conflicts Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-conflicts_algorithm) which proved to be rather efficient in the context of the problem.

However, I have recently chanced upon the [Coordinate Descent Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent) and how strikingly it resembles the Min-Conflicts Algorithm.

Probably the only difference is that in Min-Conflicts, a random variable is selected to be modified at each step whereas Coordinate Descent cycles through the variables.

Am I right to say that apart from this difference, min-conflicts and coordinate descent are essentially equivalent? If so why are classified differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I right to say that apart from this difference, min-conflicts and coordinate descent are essentially equivalent?

In the same sense that A* and BFS are essentially equivalent except for the choice of which node to visit next, yes.

> If so why are classified differently?

There are some problems for which Min-Conflicts performs asymptotically faster (in the expected-time sense) than Coordinate Descent, and vice versa. Ditto, there are some problems where one (generally) converges and the other (generally) doesn't.